# Speed and size with hidden index in postgresql

Tags: postgresql

I have a table with 1M rows **without** index, and i don't understand why when i go for : 
 `SELECT * from table WHERE id = 954000` 
 i get the result 
instantly ! I have no index how its possible to get me the answer 
instantly ? To be sure , i run a command to know the size of a possible index :
`select pg_size_pretty(pg_total_relation_size('geopost') - pg_relation_size('geopost'));` 
The result suprise me because it outputing me 40kb . I'm litle confuse now , is postgres made a kind of hidden index ?

**the query plan:** 
EXPLAIN ANALYZE
`select * from geopost where id = 954000` 
`Gather  (cost=1000.00..14682.07 rows=1 width=38) (actual time=36.633..38.140 rows=1 loops=1)`
  `Workers Planned: 2`
  `Workers Launched: 2`
  `->  Parallel Seq Scan on geopost  (cost=0.00..13681.98 rows=0 width=38) (actual time=26.701..27.117 rows=0 loops=3)`
        `Filter: (id = 954000)`
        `Rows Removed by Filter: 333333`
`Planning time: 0.087 ms`

regards

Comment: Show us the output of `\d geopost`

Answer (score 0):

Computers are fast and 1,000,000 is no longer a very large number.

Also, our query plan cut off the last line, `Execution time:`.  In my hands, it takes around 40ms to scan 1,000,000 rows with a parallel seq scan.  This is instantaneous in human terms, but is still 500 times longer than the planning time which you are (perhaps) confusing it with.